# calling base class method from polymorphic base pointer is slow

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, polymorphism

The title's pretty confusing.. Here's a minimal code to sum it up -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

enum class TYPE {base, child};

class Base {
    int n;
  protected: Base(int _n) : n(_n) {}
  public: virtual TYPE getType(){ return TYPE::base; }
};

class Child: public Base {
    int m;
  public:
    TYPE getType(){ return TYPE::child; }
    Child(int _n, int _m) : Base(_n), m(_m) {}
};

int main() {
    unique_ptr<Base> b = make_unique<Child>(6, 7);
    TYPE tB = TYPE::base;
    TYPE tC = TYPE::child;

    {
        auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::cout << (tB == b->Base::getType()) << ", ";

        auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
        cout << "Duration: " << duration << std::endl;

    }

    {
        auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::cout << (tC == b->getType()) << ", ";

        auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
        cout << "Duration: " << duration << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is as follows -

> ```
> 1, Duration: 12  // first run was 62
> 1, Duration: 0
> ```

I understand how virtual functions might be little slower in comparison to normal(compileTime-resolved) functions, but how come the above function - `b->Base::getType()` is slower than virtual method - `b->getType()`? Is it doing two trips, like virtually resolving the function and then going back up to base class? Could anyone help me understand this?

**[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/c3TE9U)**

---

Hmm, on slight modification of code to include loops, the results are clear - 
**[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/mjFpCH)**

> ```
> 1, Duration: 33
> 1, Duration: 1478051
> ```

Comment: Need more runs to measure average execution time, one run is simply not enough.

Comment: @iksemyonov I've measured them and stated as above. The first run was 62 instead of 12 and subsequent runs are ~8-12. However the code provided doesn't do such because it is a minimal example.

Comment: I mean, you should run a few hundred or thousand calls *in a loop* and then compare the average time for one function call based on that data. The current approach is an incorrect way of setting up this experiment.

Comment: @iksemyonov hmm, I was doing multiple runs of executable instead of multiple class of function inside same executable. The tables have turned and this is embarrassing :p

Comment: Your timing numbers for the one function call are way overwhelmed by the time used by the call to cout.  The initial cout call is possibly allocating memory for a buffer, and would take longer.  The first call (`b->Base::getType()`) won't be virtual, and may even be inlined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timing numbers for the one function call are overwhelmed by the time used by the call to `cout`.  The initial `cout` call is possibly allocating memory for a buffer, and would take longer.

The first call (`b->Base::getType()`) won't be virtual, and could even be inlined.